# what's suitable Web math editor for writing formula in asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, math, editor

I search for Math editors for writing formulas in asp.net
I want something like exist in http://math.stackexchange.com ,

Could any suggest a free good one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use [MathJAX](http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009/12/still-more-latex-on-web.html) or [jsMath](http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009/11/jsmath-typesetting-math-in-browser.html).  If you just want a quick image, you can use [Equation Sheet](http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009_11_01_archive.html).